# Subsets for a string

Tags: python, string, list, subset

I was trying to get every subset for a string and could not think how to do it. If anyone can help me that would be great.

```
>>> string('ab')
    a, b
>>> string('abc')
    a, b, c, ab, ac, bc,
>>> string('abcd')
    a, b, c, d, ab, bc, cd, da, abc, bcd, cda, dab,
```

These all have to be in the list and there might be n numbers of characters in the string. The program should return all the strings subsets that can be formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and list comprehension like this

```
from itertools import combinations
def myStrings(s):
    return ["".join(item) for i in range(1,len(s)) for item in combinations(s,i)]

print myStrings('ab')
print myStrings('abc')
print myStrings('abcd')
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd', 'abc', 'abd', 'acd', 'bcd']
```

Comment: your code returns every subset but can you remove the subsets that are not cyclic like they escape characters like 'abd' and 'acd'

Answer (score 0):

**Returns a subset of a string in javascript**

```js
function getSubset(str) {
  let subSet = [];
  let i, j, len = str.length; 

  for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
    for(j=i+1; j<=len; j++) {
       subSet.push(str.slice(i, j))
    }
  }
  return subSet;
}

console.log(getSubset('CAT'))
console.log(getSubset('GOD'))
```